# What parser do JRuby and Jython use for generating JVM bytecode?

Tags: jvm, jruby, antlr, jython, javacc

Do you guys know what parser JRuby and Jython use for generating JVM bytecode? Is it ANTLR or JavaCC or are they using some other parser in their implementation?

Comment: Note that ANTLR and JavaCC are not parser, but parser generators.

Answer (score 5):

JRuby seems to be answered already, so I'll add what I know about Jython.

Jython uses an [ANTLRv3](http://www.antlr.org/) generated parser to generate an AST that conforms to the spec for the one you can get from Pythons built in compile function (if you ask for AST Jython will just return after this stage). This is then fed through a custom compiler that uses the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) Java bytecode generation library to generate Java bytecode that is then loaded and executed. Jython does not (in contrast to JRuby) have an initial interpreted stage, but compiles directly to Java bytecode and lets the JVM handle it from there. Because of this I've never liked it when people describe Jython as a Python *interpreter* written in Java, I'd much rather call it a Python *implementation* for Java.

Comment: This is a succinct explanation of precisely what Jython does, and its surprisingly hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

JRuby uses a custom compiler that compile Ruby functions as needed.  This is written in Java.  This is described very well [in this blog post](http://www.realjenius.com/2009/10/06/distilling-jruby-the-jit-compiler/).

Jython probably has a similar approach.  Google searches didn't lead me to any one good document for describing how things are accomplished, but several documents mention that Jython is a Python interpreter written in Java, indicating to me that they create bytecode by compiling Java code with the compiler.